# MySQL-python install Mac

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I am trying to install MySQLdb for Python on my mac so I can use it to test.  I am running *OS X 10.11.4*.  Everywhere I look says to use

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Every time I do that I get an error saying.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4s/4wwhr6zj59sf0c4qkprqbsp80000gn/T/pip-build-042_KK/MySQL-python/
```

I am running the command just right when I open a new shell, should I change the path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

install mysql connector using homebrew `brew install mysql-connector-c` then install mysql-python using pip `pip install mysql-python` or try PyMySQL its a pure python client library, you can install using `pip install PyMySQL` and upgrade `setuptools`. `pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

Comment: brew install mysql-connector-c produces an error on macOS Sierra: Error: Cannot install mysql-connector-c because conflicting formulae are installed.

  mysql: because both install MySQL client libraries

Please `brew unlink mysql` before continuing.

Unlinking removes a formula's symlinks from /usr/local. You can
link the formula again after the install finishes. You can --force this
install, but the build may fail or cause obscure side-effects in the
resulting software.