# Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5
MySQL Server 8.0.20
Rails 6.0.2.2
Ruby 2.7.1
MySQL2 Gem 0.5.3
```

When I do a Bundle Install, I get the following error:

```
Error:[rake --tasks] rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/my-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/my-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/my-mac/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I did a search for the file:

```
libssl.1.1.dylib
```

On my drive, and came up with two of them:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
```

And

```
/usr/local/mysql-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86_64/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
```

And that last one also has a couple of aliases.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up Django with MySQL on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753805/setting-up-django-with-mysql-on-macos)

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem

Comment: ```/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"```

Comment: ```brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?